# Symfony 4 Doctrine multiple table joins in one property

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

Very new to symfony and Doctrine. I have the following tables in my database.

**mo_user**

```
id   |    email      |   password
__________________________________
9144 | summer@h.com  |   !password!
```

**mo_user_role**

```
user_id| role_id
_________________
9144   | 5
```

**mo_permission**

```
id | namespace            | name | description
______________________________________________
1  | admin                | -    |   -
2  | users                | -    |   -
3  | view_summary_report  | -    |   -
4  | view_user_statement  | -    |   -
```

**mo_role_permission**

```
role_id  | permission_id
________________________
    5    | 3
    5    | 4
```

I am trying to return an array of the permissions of the current user in this case user with id = `9144` which should be `array('view_summary_report','view_user_statement')`.

I have mapped all the tables to their corresponding entity classes. and in `MoUser.php` entity class which corresponds to `mo_user` table, I have a 
permissions method which should return the array but my join from annotations is failing,

My `getPermissions()` method in `MoUser.php`

```
/**
 * @var Collection|MoPermission[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\MoPermission")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="mo_user_role",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id",referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $permissions;

 public function getPermissions()
{
    $currentPermissions = array();
    foreach ($this->permissions->toArray() as $index => $permission) {
        $currentPermissions[] = $permission->getNamespace();
    }

    //Return default role if Roles are not assigned to this user.
    if(count($currentPermissions)>0) {
        return $currentPermissions;
    } else {
        return array('DEFAULT_PERMISSION');
    }
}
```

So I figured out the raw sql to achieve what I wanted which is below, but I would like to know the Symfony/Doctrine annotated way of achieving the following raw SQL.

```
 SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.namespace AS namespace_2, t0.name AS name_3, t0.description AS description_4 

 FROM mo_permission t0 

 LEFT JOIN mo_role_permission ON t0.id = mo_role_permission.permission_id 

 LEFT JOIN mo_user_role ON  mo_role_permission.role_id = mo_user_role.role_id

 WHERE mo_user_role.user_id = 9144;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a proper way to achieve what you're trying to do directly through property annotations with your current setup.

You could achieve what you want with one of these solution though :

- One of `mo_user_role` and `mo_role_permission` is not needed, since none of them have additional field. You should just have a `mo_user_permission` table generated by a `ManyToMany` relationship between `MoUser` and `MoPermission`, which would grant you direct access to `MoPermission` from `MoUser`'s `getPermissions()`
- Another way would be to create a service which would have a `GetPermissionsFromUser(MoUser $moUser)` method (for example), calling the proper query from the entity's repository, which you would call when needed.
- You could still achieve what you want in your `getPermissions()` method with your current setup, but you would have to loop through each relation's items to build your new result array manually.

e.g. for last point :

```
public function getPermissions() {
    $permissions = [];
    foreach($this->roles as $role) {
        foreach($role->getPermissions() as $permission) {
            permissions[] = $permission->getNamespace();
        }
    }
    return $permissions;
}
```

This would assume you have a MoRole entity, which would make sense regarding your current setup, but you didn't mention it. Otherwise, same logic could still be applied though, it's just a naming matter.

Comment: Thank you, Ill try It out, I do have a MoRole entity. thank you

Comment: Thank you, for me the last bullet point was the easiest to implement. marked it as a correct answer.

Comment: Glad it fixed your problem. Keep in mind other ways for future work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you could do that query using Doctrine (and a QueryBuilder) like...

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

class PermissionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    //....

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return array|Permission[]
     */
    public function getPermissionsForUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('permission');

        /**
         * permissions will be in a multi-dimensional array
         * with a single key per array of 'namespace'
         */
        $permissions = $queryBuilder
            ->select('permission.namespace')
            ->join('permission.role', 'role')
            ->join('role.user', 'user')
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('user', ':user'))
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();

        if (count($permissions) > 0) {
            /**
             * If there are any permissions found just return
             * the 'namespace' property from each "sub-array"
             */
            return array_column($permissions, 'namespace');
        }

        return ['DEFAULT_PERMISSION'];
    }

    //...
}
```

And then you would call it like..

```
$permissions = $repository->getPermissionsForUser($user);
```